# How to sort a 3D numpy array according to a column?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

For a 2d array, a, we can sort using

```
a = a[a[:, 0].argsort]
```

if we want to sort by column 0. How to do a similar thing for a 3d matrix?
If we have

```
a = [[[ 1.,  2., 10.],
         [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
         [ 2.,  3.,  4.]],

        [[ 2.,  3.,  4.],
         [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
         [ 1.,  2.,  3.]],

        [[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
         [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
         [ 2.,  3.,  4.]]]
```

And we want to sort according to the first column of each element of the 3d matrix?

Comment: `a = a[a[:,:,0].argsort()]` ??

Comment: Gives a (3, 3, 3, 3) array

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: A (3, 3, 3) sorted array. Sorted by the first column of each element.

Comment: We sort an array by element, but in your case your element is a whole column, we can't make comparisons like `[1,2,3] > [1,3,5]`, what you can do is compare the first element of each column, the l1 or l2 norms, max value, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help:

```
COL = 0
DIM0 = 3
a[:, a[:, :, COL].argsort()][np.diag_indices(DIM0)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Explaining what is happening in it would probably make it more helpful to the asker.